# cannot access app folder on macos even if use finder tool

Tags: python, macos

When I run a python program on Mac OS which uses a .dat file, I met an error as below:

```
Exception: Unable to load xxx detector from /app/xxx.dat
```

However, when I tried to copy the xxx.dat to the place, I cannot find the /app/ folder. It seems not "Applications". Even if I use Find->go->Go to Folder, I still cannot go to the correct place.

Comment: So you can find the `Applications` folder in `/` and so, if you have that `xxx.dat` file in the `Applications` folder, the the path would be `/Applications/xxx.dat`

Comment: If the above comment didn't help. I request you to provide more details: 
1. Python source file. 2. Did you create a `/app` folder?